# AngularJS Error: $parse:ueoe Unexpected End of Expression error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to utilized a little AngularJS on my front-end but keep running into issues with pushing data from my backend.  My backend is Node.js/Express/Mongoose/Mongo with Handlebars templating.

I'm trying to pass an array into an Angular $scope variable but it keeps bombing with the below Unexpected End of Expression Error:

```
Error: [$parse:ueoe] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$parse/ueoe?p0=posts%3D%7B
at Error (native)
at http://localhost:3000/js/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:6:416
at Object.s.peekToken (http://localhost:3000/js/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:209:514)
at Object.s.object (http://localhost:3000/js/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:208:336)
at Object.s.primary (http://localhost:3000/js/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:205:503)
at Object.s.unary (http://localhost:3000/js/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:205:342)
at Object.s.multiplicative (http://localhost:3000/js/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:205:88)
at Object.s.additive (http://localhost:3000/js/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:204:430)
at Object.s.relational (http://localhost:3000/js/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:204:265)
at Object.s.equality (http://localhost:3000/js/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:204:90) <div class="container ng-scope" ng-controller="infiniteScrollCtrl" ng-init="posts={" _id":"55fb04878dabb2842d3deaeb","title":"my="" sixth="" post"}>
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MyController" ng-init="posts={{{ data.posts }}}">
<div class="row" ng-repeat='post in posts'>
    <div>
      {[{ post.title }]};
    </div>
</div>
```

The Angular interpolater symbol was reconfigured to {[{ so as not to conflict with handlebars.

```
app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
});
```

And here is what data.posts looks like:

```
{"_id":"55fb04878dabb2842d3deaeb","title":"My Test Post"}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your actual code missing that double-quote on the container `ng-init` attribute?

Comment: This is not the [appropriate use](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) for `ng-init`.  `ng-init` is a directive, with a priority, which means that it may or may not have run when other components expect data to be available.  Aside from that, you state that you changed your `$interpolateProvider` to `{[{ }]}` but the `ng-init` statement is using `{{{ }}}`.

Comment: looking at your error, vs the actual code you posted, it's not even clear what you tried to pass here.  This is what the error is saying that your code looks like: `ng-init="posts={" _id":"55fb04878dabb2842d3deaeb","title":"my="" sixth="" post"};="" `.  To me, that looks like an invalid JSON object, assuming that using `ng-init` were appropriate here.

Comment: So, I'm using ng-init to to save data being passed in from the back-end (in data.posts) to a $scope variable (posts), so that I can iterate through the objects with ng-repeat.  the {{{ data.posts }}} is not Angular, it is handlebars formatting for data interpolation.  Yes, I agree the format of the actual JSON object does look odd, but I'm not sure why.  As I said, the actual object in data.posts seems clean.

Comment: I definitely recommend reviewing what handlebars is outputting here then, because angular is definitely not able to handle the object as it is being passed.

Comment: So, the issue is the double quotes in the JSON object I am passing.  It appears to be conflicting in the ng-init.  i.e.  passing the following works: 

{'_id':'55fb04878dabb2842d3deaeb','title':'My Test Post'}

Comment: `ng-init="posts=data.posts"`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `[]` in `{[{ post.title }]};`?

It should be:

```
    <div>
      {{ post.title }};
    </div>
```

Comment: OP is using a custom interpolator

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer to the question.  The post specifically described the reason that they are not using the normal syntax here.